# Verilog Error - Elaboration time constant

Tags: verilog

Variable declarations:

```
output reg a, b, c;
```

What is wrong with the following, coded in Verilog:

```
generate

if (!a && !b && !c)
    call    call1(param1, param2, param3);

endgenerate
```

I get the following error on the `if` statement line:

```
Error - unknown or bad value for genvar
Elaboration time unknown or bad value encountered for generate if-statement
condition expression. 
Please make sure it is elaboration time constant.
```

I even tried the following:

```
always @* begin

if (!a && !b && !c)
    call    call1(param1, param2, param3);

end
```

When I do what's immediately above (the always block), I get the following syntax error:

```
Token is '('

call    call1(param1, param2, param3);
                     ^
```

Comment: Are a,b, c genvars? Could you expand the example to cover the variable declarations. NB there not calls they are instances, your describing physical hardware not a programming routine.

Comment: Basically I would just like to include an if-statement in a couple of modules, but I get the elaboration time unknown error when I don't include the `always @*`header. And when I do include the `always @*` header, I get incorrect output (x's). P.S. How do I determine if something is a genvar? And what does NB stand for?

Comment: NB: [on wikipeida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene), just means take note.

Answer (score 3):

There looks to be some confuse with the way you are using verilog, in particular from the naming conventions you have used.

A compiling version of your example using generates [on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CVH):

```
module test;

  localparam a = 0;
  localparam b = 0;
  localparam c = 0;

  generate
    if (!a && !b && !c) begin
      call    call1(param1, param2, param3);
    end
  endgenerate

endmodule

module call(
  input param1,
  input param2,
  input param3
);
endmodule
```

This instantiates call, ie creates the hardware if a,b and c are 0. Since we can not create and destroy hardware a,b,c must be constants.

You have called your module **call**, which sounds like your viewing it a s a software function call. It is not it is a hardware block.

Your ports have been named **param**, ports are not parameters they represent physical wires in hardware that would connect the module to each other.

It sounds like your actually trying to have selective logic in which case you need combinatorial hardware to select which output to use.

```
wire out1,out2,result;

call         call1     (input1, input2, out1); //<-- Hardware always exists
othercall    instance_2(input1, input2, out2);

always @* begin
  if (!a && !b && !c)
    result = out1;     //<-- Output from different modules selected
  else 
    result  = out2;
end
```

If your not selecting between two outputs:

```
call         call1     (input1, input2, out1); //<-- Hardware always exists

always @* begin
  if (!a && !b && !c)
    result = out1;     //<-- Output from module selected
  else 
    result  = 'b0;     // Otherwise drive 0
end
```

Comment: Would `initial begin` work as well? I get two different outputs, one for each. How should I know which one to use?

Comment: @thetypist No, initial is only evaluated once, so the selection would be static. ie result would never change. I do not understand your 2 different outputs. result should always be driven.